# What does the @mutateState decorator mean in a NEAR smart contract (web assembly)?

Tags: nearprotocol

From some examples using `near-sdk-as`, I have seen that they use the `@mutateState` decorator, but I'm not sure what it does.

This is a snippet from the starter example on [Learn NEAR](https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-sdk-as/blob/main/src/singleton/assembly/index.ts):

```
  // write the given value at the given key to account (contract) storage
  @mutateState()
  write(key: string, value: string): string {
    storage.set(key, value)
    return `✅ Data saved. ( ${this.storageReport()} )`
  }
```

I saw from this [answer on a different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67386824/1471485) question that:

> If the method is decorated with `@mutateState` then the instance is
> written back to storage after the method call.

But I don't know what that means. I thought `storage.set(key,value)` would store the data without needing to use the decorator. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A singleton class is special.  It's a class exported by the entry file. It represents a single class that is the state of the contract.  Before a method is called the class's state is loaded and is passed as `this`.  Normally this method will run and return.  However, if the state of the contract is changed or mutated, you need to add this decorator so that before the method returns the state is written back to storage.

In Rust this is handled by the type of `self`.  `&self` is immutable so you can't change the state of the contract. `&mut self` is mutable and this method will also be written back to storage.

The example you posted also doesn't demonstrate this.

```js
@mutateState
setName(name: string): void {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: thanks @sirwillem -- I've updated the repo to justify the use of `@mutateState` decorator https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-sdk-as/commit/889b3f47317b00a1a773e25ba9283365d8a23586

Comment: I see. It means that the decorator wasn't necessary in the snippet I posted, since the singleton wasn't actually changing it's state (only storage). 
After looking at the updated example by @amgando, it also makes more sense now. Thanks